# Syntax error while installing seaborn using conda

Tags: ipython, anaconda, seaborn, conda

I've recently tried to install seaborn on ipython, which the latter was installed using anaconda. However, when I ran  `conda install seaborn`, i was returned with a syntax error. I tried again with `conda install -c anaconda seaborn=0.7.0` this time but syntax error was returned again. Apologies for my limited programming knowledge, but could anyone provide advice on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you include the syntax error?

Comment: Can you alternately try installing w/ pip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conda` is a command line tool, not a Python function. You should be typing these commands in a bash (or tcsh, etc.) shell, not in the IPython interpreter.